# A dataset of drugs or molecules that failed the FDA approval process

Tags: toxicity, drugs

I am looking for a dataset of bad drugs, the opposite of FDA approved drugs.

[There is this database of withdrawn drugs](http://cheminfo.charite.de/withdrawn/index.html), but these drugs were withdrawn after making it into the market.

Is there any such dataset of drugs that failed the FDA approval process because of their toxicity or poor pharmacokinetics properties?